# Unable to registerUser for Hyperledger Fabric - fabcar sample project

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I try to run sample application as stated here : http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html

Everything looks good until I ran this command : `node registerUser`

**Error** :

> Store
>   path:/Users/johndoe/Desktop/myProject/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
>   Successfully loaded admin from persistence Failed to register: Error:
>   fabric-ca request register failed with errors
>   [[{"code":0,"message":"No identity type provided. Please provide
>   identity type"}]]

I checked logs by running `docker logs ca.example.com` command:

> 2017/11/08 09:43:07 [DEBUG] Successful authentication of 'admin'
>
> 2017/11/08 09:43:07 [DEBUG] Register request received
>
> 2017/11/08 09:43:07 [DEBUG] Received registration request from admin: &{RegistrationRequest:{Name:user1 Type: Secret:<> MaxEnrollments:1 Affiliation:org1.department1 Attributes:[] CAName:}}
>
> 2017/11/08 09:43:07 [DEBUG] Registration of 'user1' failed: No identity type provided. Please provide identity type
>
> 2017/11/08 09:43:07 [INFO] 172.18.0.1:60190 - "POST /api/v1/register" 0

Did I miss anything here? I successfully ran `node enrollAdmin.js` and able to get the generated `eCert` & `key material` in **hfc-key-store**

Comment: what is ur development environment? and can u also upload screenshot of ur working terminal result

Answer (score 15):

In my case, adding the user's role type make it works.

```
return fabric_ca_client.register({enrollmentID: 'user1', affiliation: 'org1.department1',role: 'client'}, admin_user);
```

Comment: I have fixed this issue in fabric-samples using the same change https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/commit/25f6091b86be3e66078102f381c0dc1cbc3fe7f6

Comment: same issue is there in balance transfer example

Answer (score 2):

I was having same trouble but after adding role: 'client' to the registeUser file it ran and registered successfully.

**before- adding the *role: 'client'***

```
Anoops-MacBook:fabcar anoopdixit$ node registerUser.js
Store path:/Users/anoopdixit/Documents/Blockchain/projects/Hyperledger-Fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded admin from persistence
Failed to register: **Error:** fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"No identity type provided. Please provide identity type"}]]
Anoops-MacBook:fabcar anoopdixit$
```

**after:adding the *role: 'client'**

```
Anoops-MacBook:fabcar anoopdixit$ node registerUser.js
 Store path:/Users/anoopdixit/Documents/Blockchain/projects/Hyperledger-Fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded admin from persistence
Successfully registered user1 - secret:aMgShhReEivm
Successfully enrolled member user "user1" 
**User1 was successfully registered** and enrolled and is ready to intreact with the fabric network
Anoops-MacBook:fabcar anoopdixit$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the project [balance transfer](https://github.com/chandrakanthm/fabric_balance_transfer) to accommodate the role attribute and modified the testAPI.sh file which contains curl call to enroll a new user.